# How to write a python function that returns an integer's digit that is the same number as the index without using an array?

Tags: python

Write a function named index_of_digit that takes two integer parameter, number and index. The function should return the integer digit that is at that index

Tried:

```
def index_of_digit(number, index):

  for i in range(number):

    if number[i] == index:
      return i
    else:
     print("None")
temp = index_of_digit(1724,0)

print(index_of_digits)
```

Expected Input/Output:

> index_of_digit(1724, 0) --> 1
>
> index_of_digit(25670, 3) --> 7

Error Message: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: convert the integer to a string and index the string

Comment: turn 1724 into "1724" and then find the index in the string of 1724? @Chris_Rands

Comment: @OcasoProtal just added my error message

Answer (score 1):

```
def index_of_digit(number, index):
    return int(str(number)[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

*"The function should return the integer digit that is at that index"*, then your logic is wrong. You can easily get the index of number if you'll parse that number to string. Like this:

```
def index_of_digit(number, index):
    try:
        print(str(number)[index])
    except:
        print("None")
```

**Input/Output**

> index_of_digit(1724,0) -> 1
>
> index_of_digit(1724,7) -> None
>
> index_of_digit(25670,3) -> 7

Comment: i would argue that an IndexError is the correct output of `index_of_digit(1724, 7)`

Comment: also you should return something, and it probably shouldn't be a string

Comment: @Stael, that error is catch by `except:`, you can try it.

Comment: i know - but why would you catch it? it is the correct error for that operation

Comment: The _"None"_ is actually saying that.

Comment: also a blind try except like that will catch the error if index is not an int, which is misleading. the default error handling in python is far more useful than you catching the error and printing 'none'

Comment: sorry, this is a pet peeve of mine - 'none' is saying none, not 'index out of range' if this was part of a programme i was working on and it printed 'none' and carried on i would have no idea why or where, but if it said 'index out of range' and crashed with a line number, that would be really easy to debug. you've overwritten useful python functionality with bad, unclear functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here a modification of your code (based on solution in comments) that should give your desired output:

```
def index_of_digit(number, index):
    if type(number) != int:
        print("Error: the first argument must be an integer.")
        return
    number_string = str(number)
    try:
      number_string[index]
      return int(number_string[index])
    except:
     print("Index is larger than the number of digits")
temp = index_of_digit(1724,0)

print(temp)
```

Comment: if i do `index_of_string('hello', 2)` does it print `"Index is larger than the number of digits"`

Comment: what i was getting at is that your error handling is at best unnecessary and at worst dangerous because you're overwriting the normal error which would be something like 'cannot convert 'l' to int' with your own message, but because you are catching all errors, rather than specifically the index error then you accidentally overwrite a correct error message with your own incorrect one. but meh.

Comment: yeah of course.. you are right, but mine it's just a stupid snippet to inspire the author of the question to then refine its solution